# Init error Unable to open socket - C++ file upload

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to upload a file to my server using c++, but I keep getting an error saying:

```
Init error: Unable to open socket.
```

I already tried adding new libraries such as `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <winsock2.h>` but nothing seems to help.

C++ is not my main language so I feel a bit lost.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    HWND hwnd_win = GetForegroundWindow();
    ShowWindow(hwnd_win, SW_HIDE);

    string filea = "clerks.txt"; 
    string fileb = "products.txt";
    string filec = "products2.txt"; 


     ShellExecute(
        NULL,
        _T("open"),
        _T("C:\\connect\\w_icrcom.exe"),
        _T("r clerks.txt 5"), 
        _T("C:\\connect"),
        SW_HIDE);

    ShellExecute(
        NULL,
        _T("open"),
        _T("C:\\connect\\w_icrcom.exe"),
        _T("r products.txt 80"), 
        _T("C:\\connect"),
        SW_HIDE);

    ShellExecute(
        NULL,
        _T("open"),
        _T("C:\\connect\\w_icrcom.exe"),
        _T("r products2.txt 81"), 
        _T("C:\\connect"),
        SW_HIDE);

    //cout << "File Found" << endl;
    // Sending the file to the ftp server in order to process it with PHP
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL,0);
    hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "ftp.domain.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "login", "pass", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
    FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, filea.c_str(), "/public_html/rota/application/incoming/clerks.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, fileb.c_str(), "/public_html/rota/application/incoming/products.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, filec.c_str(), "/public_html/rota/application/incoming/products2.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I think the error is coming from the ShellExecute, because when I leave only one Shell it works fine, but when I leave 3 of them it returns the error.

Comment: There are way too many reasons that a socket cannot be opened to be able to assist you without further information. Simple possibilities are a firewall blocked you, there is no server at the endpoint, and the server at the endpoint does not have an FTP server running. All of these are runtime errors, so adding more libraries isn't going to help.

Comment: The error `"Init error: Unable to open socket."` is not in the code you have shown, so where is it coming from exactly? From one of the `.exe` files you are spawning?  And you are not doing *any* error handling in the code you have shown.

Comment: I'm getting it from the .exe, the server endpoint is correct. Gonna try to look for some handling for the errors.

Answer (score -1):

i changed

```
ShellExecute(
        NULL,
        _T("open"),
        _T("C:\\connect\\w_icrcom.exe"),
        _T("r clerks.txt 5"), 
        _T("C:\\connect"),
        SW_HIDE);
```

to

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
    ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpFile = "C:\\connect\\w_icrcom.exe";        
    ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "r products2.txt 81";   
    ShExecInfo.lpDirectory ="C:\\connect";
    ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE;
    ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL; 
    ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
    WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

Now the error seems to be gone.